# Did early-20th-Century poskim speak to reliance on ingredients lists on labels?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

It seems to be common knowledge that before the OU hechsher on food packages, American Jews frequently relied on the ingredients lists on labels to identify kosher food.

Did poskim of the day oppose this practice, or discuss whether it was proper?

Are there distinctions here between Ashkenazic and Sephardic views?

Comment: What was the alternative? If someone was going to oppose it they must have had an alternative. Home gardening?

Comment: See Yoreh Deah 96:4 that buying various minimally processed foods from gentiles was pretty common, and that predates food labeling laws entirely.

Comment: @Double AA I suppose that alternatives include opining about changes in the way food is made, advice to favor (or avoid) certain brands (or factories), and advice to make certain kinds of food at home (rather than buying them ready-made). This would not require home gardening, although I suppose that gardening was a possibility for many. The advice may have allowed raw fruits and vegetables while still imposing some limits.

Comment: you may enjoy https://seforimblog.com/2021/12/gelatin-supposed-retractions-and-abraham-goldstein-part-1/